# Firestore query filter on multiple fileds

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some trouble to make a query which allow me to filter on multiple dynamic fields.

For exemple with this document type i would like to fetch all documents with dynamics filters (I don't care about the value in other fields).

I can't make a composite index for all possiblity because with 25-30 fields which can be a potential filter i reach the 200 index limit.

I haven't see any way to use `whereArrayContains` with multiple value.

```
exemple:
array -> [computer, internet, ps4,switch]
filter -> whereArrayContains("gears", "internet" AND "switch")
```

So if someone have any idea how i can achieve this or any workaround... It would be very appreciate because i'm trying to "fix" this problem since few days without any success

### filter exemple:

```
- internet + wifi + computer = true
- internet + ps4 + tv + xbox = true
- ps4 + xbox = true
- any random génération
```

### doc type:

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you try adding multiple `whereArrayContains()` clauses?

Comment: Sadly use something like  ```ref.collection("rentals").whereArrayContains("gears", "wifi" ).whereArrayContains("gears", "xbox" )``` give me ` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. Queries only support having a single array-contains filter.`

Comment: Darn... I sort'of knew that, but hoped I misremembered. In that case, I think your only option would be to add the tag combination to the array, so `["gears", "internet", "ps2", "gears_internet", "gears_ps4", "internet_ps4"]`. As you allow searching for more than two tags, the number of combinations will explode. But it'll still only require a single index on the array field, so you won't run out of your maximum number of indexes.

Comment: Yes unfortunately for 20 tags it's 400 combinations... But two tags is useless for me. For the moment i use realtime database with geofire and use key for filter and after i make many query for each document. But my goal is to handle all inside firestore (already done geofire on firestore thx your conference ^^). Do you think there is no other way to make something like this ? Even if i have to change my database structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can filter your items using only one `whereArrayContains()` method call. If you will use more than one, the following error will occur:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. Queries only support having a single array-contains filter.

If you need to filter on more than one property, you'll need to change the logic of structuring your database by creating a property for each individual filter that you have and then chain `whereEqualTo()` method calls. I know it sounds a little weird but this is how Cloud Firestore works.

Your schema should like this:

```
documentId: { 
    "computer": true,
    "internet": true,
    "ps4": true,
    "switch": true
}
```

To find all the items which are `"gears", "internet" and "switch"`, you should use a query that looks like this:

```
Query query = yourCollectionRef.
    .whereEqualTo("gears", true)
    .whereEqualTo("internet", true)
    .whereEqualTo("switch", true);
```

You can also store those filters in a map, like in the following schema:

```
documentId: {
    gears: {
        "computer": true,
        "internet": true,
        "ps4": true,
        "switch": true
    }
}
```

And the corresponding query should look like this:

```
Query query = yourCollectionRef.
    .whereEqualTo("gears.gears", true)
    .whereEqualTo("gears.internet", true)
    .whereEqualTo("gears.switch", true);
```

Comment: It's my current logic, but it's working only if you always all your filter inside the query. And that's the source of my problem because you need a composite index for every combinations. It can be working if something like this exist `.whereEqualTo("gears.internet", Field.IGNORE)`

Comment: Unfortunately, something like this `.whereEqualTo("gears.internet", Field.IGNORE)` does **not** exist. In your case, you should also consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup. This means that you can denormalize the data by creating a collection of `gears & internet & switch` and add all the corresponding object in there. So it's a trade between the number of read/rwites and the number of indexes.

Comment: Sadly i can't denormalize the data in my case. Now i need to choose the best solution between keep my data split on RTDB/Firestore with functions to sync or use only firestore and filter on client side with the extra read cost...

Comment: In that case, I think you should go ahead with a mix from your solutions. Firebase realtime database is working very well along with Cloud Firestore and for sure Cloud Functions will be much of a help.